# Firebase collectionGroup query security rules not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've seen this question a zillion times, always answered by the extremely helpful @doug-stevenson ... but for the life of me after carefully reading through these I still can't see what i'm doing wrong.

Query (swift): 
`DB.collectionGroup("sessions").whereField("email", arrayContains: "tim@testing.com")`

I tried just hard-setting a value in the rules like this (see second rule):

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /tenants-v1/{tenantId}/{doc=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null
                  && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/tenants-v1/$(tenantId)).data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }

    match /{path=**}/sessions/{session} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null
                     && resource.data.tenantId == 'timsolo';
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

... and made sure `/tenants-v1/timsolo/galleries/Dzim0sqH9ewwWY7C43oo/sessions/D6Ffo9VYWfcEgXaLVKJb` contains a field `tenantId` with value string `timsolo`.

**That did not work as expected**: the query returns `Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Sanity test: taking out the last line of the second rule above (so it just allows all authenticated requests) causes this collectionGroup query to work as expected.

What's going on, why can't I check `resource.data` ?

End desire is to check `auth.token.tenantIds`, a custom-claim on the token, against the value in the data. I'd prefer to check against `resource['__name__'][4]` because that's the value I actually care about, but that doesn't work either. Anyways let's get the basic working first...

Comment: Can you share the entire code for your security rules. Also what is the exact query used for testing your rule? (Not `DB.collectionGroup("sessions").whereField("email", arrayContains: "tim@testing.com")` I guess).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec OK I updated the question to show all the rules. No, that is indeed the entire query used for testing... there's a `getDocuments` on the end to execute the query, maybe you mean that part is missing in the above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems indeed to come from this part:

```
... && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/tenants-v1/$(tenantId)).data.uid == request.auth.uid;
```

If you try to simply query for the `/tenants-v1/timsolo/galleries/Dzim0sqH9ewwWY7C43oo/sessions/D6Ffo9VYWfcEgXaLVKJb` document, you need to have an `uid` field in the `/tenants-v1/timsolo/` document with the value corresponding to the uid of the authenticated user.

---

Note that you can easily detect that by using the "Rules Playground", see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) for more info.

Comment: Hi Renaud thanks for your help. I don't understand: I thought that each of the 3 rules are effectively OR'd together, so any one `true` would suffice, and only the second rule would be used anyways since it is the only one that matches a collectionGroup query?

Comment: ... and as it happens, that `uid` field is indeed in `/tenants-v1/timsolo` matching `auth.uid` as you specified. I don't think it would need to be for a collectionGroup query, but it is there in any case.

Comment: I guess that the [overlapping](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements) does not work with these paths which somehow do not really overlap (to be tested more thoroughly...).

Comment: "that uid field is indeed in /tenants-v1/timsolo matching auth.uid as you specified." That strange, because with this field it should work, according to the "Rules Playground".

Comment: Note that I am not using the `DB.collectionGroup("sessions").whereField("email", arrayContains: "tim@testing.com")` query, which obviously would not work with these rules.

Comment: agreed that it is strange. I just double-checked again, the `uid` value is there and my client is making the collectionGroup request with that uid (authenticated).

Comment: You keep mentioning the rules playground, but I see no way to use it with collectionGroup queries which are fundamentally different than the `get...` queries that the playground supports....?

Comment: What I a not sure about is which exact query do you use from your client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216087/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-xaphod).